# Returning a list of values with replacement values and cursors

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have to write a code which returns a list of countries when you write the name of a continent. The countries must be within that continent, of course. When that list is returned, the column VISUALIZADO from the table PAISES will be updated with the value 'Yes'. A cursor must be used. Names are in Spanish since my teacher wants us to do it, but these words are easy to understand. The two tables for this exercise are these:

```
CREATE TABLE PAISES (

COD_PAIS NUMBER(3),

NOMBRE VARCHAR2(30),

COD_CONTINENTE NUMBER(3),

VISUALIZADO VARCHAR2(2)

);

CREATE TABLE CONTINENTES (

COD_CONTINENTE NUMBER(3),

NOMBRE VARCHAR2(30)

);
```

What I have written:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
v_ncont continentes.nombre%TYPE := &nombre_continente;
v_codcont continentes.cod_continente%TYPE;

cursor listado_paises is 
select cod_pais, nombre, cod_continente, visualizado
from paises;

BEGIN
if v_ncont = continentes.nombre THEN
UPDATE paises
SET visualizado = 'Si'
WHERE paises.cod_continente = continentes.cod_continente;

END if;

END;
```

It is not working, obviously, but I don't know what should I do! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you want to return a list of countries, why are you using `update`?

Comment: Yes, I want to return a list of countries, but I want to update de value of the column VISUALIZADO too! I mean, both things must happen in the same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been trying to do this for days and I have finally found the solution.

```
DECLARE
no_existe EXCEPTION;
variable number;
CURSOR listado_paises is
SELECT *
FROM paises
WHERE paises.cod_continente in
(select cod_continente FROM continentes WHERE nombre = '&escribe_nombre_cont');


BEGIN
for i in listado_paises loop
UPDATE paises
SET visualizado ='Si'
WHERE cod_continente = i.cod_continente;

SELECT count (*) into variable
FROM paises
WHERE paises.cod_continente in
(select cod_continente FROM continentes WHERE nombre = '&escribe_nombre_cont');

IF variable = 0 THEN
RAISE no_existe;
END IF;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Nombre pais: ' || i.nombre);
COMMIT;
END LOOP;
EXCEPTION 
WHEN no_existe THEN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('El continente no existe, por favor, revise el nombre'); 
END;
```

It is not perfect because the exception message won't show up, but i'm writting a new question after that so that we can find a solution to this!

Answer (score 0):

You should use your cursor in the loop . Can you try this

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
v_ncont continentes.nombre%TYPE := &nombre_continente;
v_codcont continentes.cod_continente%TYPE;

cursor listado_paises is 
select cod_pais, nombre, cod_continente, visualizado
from paises;

BEGIN

for l in listado_paises
loop
if v_ncont = l.nombre THEN
UPDATE paises
SET visualizado = 'Si'
WHERE paises.cod_continente = l.cod_continente;

END if;
end loop;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks! But this didn't really work for me :( I finally managed to do it, i'm posting what worked for me now! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Update with an `inner view` and `FOR loop` with `DBMS_OUTPUT` to print the data as follows:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

UPDATE (
    SELECT P.COD_PAIS, P.VISUALIZADO, C.COD_CONTINENTE
      FROM PAISES P JOIN CONTINENTES C ON P.COD_CONTINENTE = C.COD_CONTINENTE
     WHERE C.NOMBRE = '&NOMBRE_CONTINENTE'
) SET VISUALIZADO = 'Si';
COMMIT;

FOR DATAA IN (
    SELECT P.PAISES
      FROM PAISES P JOIN CONTINENTES C ON P.COD_CONTINENTE = C.COD_CONTINENTE
     WHERE C.NOMBRE = '&NOMBRE_CONTINENTE'
) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DATAA.PAISES);
END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks! But this didn't really work for me :( I finally managed to do it, i'm posting what worked for me now! Thanks again :)